# React input field not updating when props passed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

I am using redux for simple POC. I am passing props to component. However when I assign it to input box, the input box is not updating.

My component code:

CurrenctConverter.js

```js
handleAmountchange(e) {
    debugger;
    var payload = e.target.value
    store.dispatch({ type: "Add", val: payload })

}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            Currency Converter
            USD <input type="text" onChange={this.debounceEventHandler(this.handleAmountchange, 1000)} value={this.props.globalstate.val}></input> **this inputbox not working**
            INR <input type="text"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Convert"></input>
        </div>
    )
}
```

redux store:

I am getting props from this store

```js
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

var initialstate = {
    val: 100
}
const MyReducer = (state = initialstate, action) => {
    if (action.type = "Add") {
        return {
            ...state,
            val: action.val
        }
    }  
    return state;  
}

var mystore = createStore(MyReducer); 
export default mystore;
```

Comment: Please update with the code where you add the redux state to your component.

Comment: <div className="App">
          <CurrencyConverter globalstate={Store.getState()} />
        </div >

Comment: Use [`react-redux`](https://react-redux.js.org/). That is not the proper way to connect redux state to a react component.

Comment: yeah, i am going to do that next , i was following a tutorial , 
but i am not able to understand this issue,

Answer (score 0):

In the reducer, please update the code as

```js
var initialstate = {
    val: 100
}
const MyReducer = (state = initialstate, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'Add':
        let updatedState={
            ...state,
            val: action.val
        }
      return updatedState;

      default:
        return state;
}


var mystore = createStore(MyReducer); 
export default mystore;
```

Comment: its still not working,can you share codepen link for the same

Comment: @SohanPatil Its more helpful if you give an explanation of what is wrong and how to fix it in your answer, rather than just a block of code. It looks like the only difference is you made it into a `switch` instead of `if...else`. A `switch` is probably preferred, but will not make a difference functionally.